# Access parent component reference from xtype's initComponent method

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, web-frontend, xtype

I have created a custom xtype named `MaterialSelector` and used in one of my ext views.

I need to refer parent views from the `initComponent` function of my custom xtype.
When I console.log `this.xtypesChain` from `initComponent` method it returns following array of xtypes

> ["component", "box", "container", "fieldset", "MaterialSelector"]

When I try to access parent views by xtype like: `this.findParentByType('fieldset')` script always returns `undefined`. Whether I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: did you try ownerCt or this.down('fieldset')?

Comment: @Sreek521 yes I have tried both and none of them worked. OwnerCt gives "undefined" and this.down('fieldset') gives error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"